# How to Programmatically Map Drive for SQL Server Session

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, xp-cmdshell

How can a drive (e.g. y) be mapped in C# to a network shared location? The mapped drive needs to be known by a SQL session. This is for backing up SQL databases from a C# application to the mapped drive (e.g. y). Would like to do it programmatically to allow easily changing the mapped drive network location, user and password.

Within SSMS / SQL session, I could create a mapped drive in a query window:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use y: \\host11\special\temp temppassword /user:host11\sphr /persistent:no'
```

I could then backup the SQL Server databases from the C# application. Wondering, how do I do this in C#?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Look at `Process.Start()`

Comment: Can't you backup locally then copy to a UNC? Then you don't need to map a drive (which is fraught with complications, especially if you want to make the SQL Server 'see' a drive mapped by something else). If you must do it, what's to stop you submitting that drive mapping SQL from your C# application?

Comment: Nick, I can make your "copy to a UNC" solution work. Perfect and thanks!

Comment: Thanks John! I will look to do that next time.

Answer (score 1):

The C#/.Net equivalent of MSSQL "EXEC xp_cmdshell" is [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I thought you might also be able to do it with WMI, but it looks like that's not really practical for this use case:

[Querying access to a UNC path on a remote machine via WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293625/querying-access-to-a-unc-path-on-a-remote-machine-via-wmi)

NOTE:

One problem I recall is that, when the MSSQL service runs in the context of "LocalSystem", you *cannot* access any network resources (like disk shares).  Here are some workarounds:

[How to grant network access to LocalSystem account?](https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account)

Comment: I think the tricky part is getting C# to map a drive in the same session as SQL Server is running.